# Фильтрация строк по части составного индекса

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Большая просьба помочь с решение следующей проблемы. Есть `DataFrame` с мультииндексом. Необходимо выбрать из фрейма все строки, индексы `lev1` и `lev2` которых присутствуют в составном индексе с `lev0='type1'`. Соответственно, все комбинации (`lev1`, `lev2`) которые есть только в `type2` в итоговой выборке отсутствуют.

In:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['type1', 'type1', 'type1', 'type2', 'type2'], 
                    ['a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'a0', 'a1'], ['b0', 'b1', 'b2', 'b1', 'b1']],
                    names=['lev0', 'lev1', 'lev2']))
```

Out:

```
                 a
lev0  lev1 lev2
type1 a0    b0   1
      a1    b1   2
      a2    b2   3
type2 a0    b1   4
      a1    b1   5
```

Т.е. для данной постановки ответ должен быть следующим:

```
                 a
lev0  lev1 lev2
type1 a0    b0   1
      a1    b1   2
      a2    b2   3
type2 a1    b1   5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуте так:

```
In [157]: idx = data.query("lev0 != 'type1'").index.droplevel(0).difference(data.query("lev0 == 'type1'").index.droplevel(0))

In [158]: data.loc[~data.index.droplevel(0).isin(idx)]
Out[158]:
                 a
lev0  lev1 lev2
type1 a0   b0    1
      a1   b1    2
      a2   b2    3
type2 a1   b1    5
```

Comment: С небольшой модификацией получилось, то что нужно.
Огромное спасибо!

Comment: @Eximer, а что за модификация (если не секрет)?

Comment: Идея абсолютно Ваша. Просто немного переписал:  
`inx = data.xs('type1').index.unique()`
`data = data[data.index.droplevel(0).isin(inx)]`